# What is default package version installing by npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

when I install a new package in node js project with npm, without specifying a exact version, what is the package version going to install by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the "latest" as indicated by the package information.

Source : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

That is *usually* set as the latest stable release version, usually not the beta version and other unstable releases. But again, it all depends on each package, this is just some configuration information to be set by the maintainer(s) of the package.